# How to open specific screen on receiving a file shared by another application

Tags: flutter, share, intentfilter

I have a requirement, when user clicks on a button in my flutter app, i will redirect user to other app with which i don't have access. Then from that app user needs to share a file. Using intent filters i am receiving the file in my ReceiveIntent.java class

AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <activity
        android:label="SampleApp"
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="com.sampleapp.example.ReceiveIntent"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/zip"/>

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Java Code

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
      // Get intent, action and MIME type
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("application/zip")) {
            handleSharedZIP(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/*")) {
            handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
        }
    }
}

 private void handleSharedZIP(Intent intent) {
    try {
        // pass the the path received from the intent filters to password unlock screen. So 
 that we can verify and Extract the data there.
        Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        sharedZIP = uri.toString();
        sharedZIPMethodChannel.invokeMethod("getSharedZIP",sharedZIP);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
        Log.d("error",e.getMessage().toString());
    }
  }
```

Everything is OK till here. But i want t redirect user to password unlock screen from here.I struck here.
I tried Method Channels but flutter widget which listening to that method channel not getting triggered,

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.